# How to config Wix in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, e-commerce, velo

I am trying to configure the wix to my wordpress project but i dont have any idea whether we can do it or not or if anyone can help by an alternate way to connect backend to wordpress project

I havent tried anything for the time i amm a brgineer to work on wordpress need help and proper guidance

Comment: Wix is a completely different closed system, and you cannot do that. But if you can be more clear what you want to configure may be I can suggest you something